# curl in non-interactive mode

Tags: command-line, scripting, curl

I am trying to automate stuff which includes installing rust through

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh .
```

This is interactive and queries for user-input to choose from i.e. "1" "2" or "3".

I am not able to figure out how to input values automatically.

For example with `apt-get`, there is a `-y` option try to capture and input for prompt.

Not sure, how it is done for `curl`.

Answer (score 5):

Checking the script file, you can use the `-y` option:

```
% sh <(curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf) -h
rustup-init 1.18.3 (302899482 2019-05-22)
The installer for rustup

USAGE:
    rustup-init [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

FLAGS:
    -v, --verbose           Enable verbose output
    -y                      Disable confirmation prompt.
        --no-modify-path    Don't configure the PATH environment variable
    -h, --help              Prints help information
    -V, --version           Prints version information

OPTIONS:
        --default-host <default-host>              Choose a default host triple
        --default-toolchain <default-toolchain>    Choose a default toolchain to install
        --default-toolchain none                   Do not install any toolchains
```

To add `-y` as an argument in that pipeline, use `sh`'s -`s` option:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
```

`-s` tells `sh` to read commands from input, and `--` passes the remaining arguments to the script (read from input), so `-y` is set as an argument to the script.

Or, if you have bash, use process substitution:

```
sh <(curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf) -y
```